# Reading default qgis-auth.db from a script

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I try to read username and password from the `qgis-auth.db`, the latter having been configured under QGIS (3.6.1, Ubuntu).

Here is my code :

```py
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

argvb = list(map(os.fsencode, sys.argv))
qgisapp = QgsApplication(argvb, True)
qgisapp.initQgis()

authM = qgisapp.authManager()
authM.setMasterPassword("myMasterPassword", True)  # returns True
print(authM.authenticationDatabasePath())
# returns '/home/me/.local/share/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db'
```

it's not the QGIS3 default profile location, which is :

```
/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

I'd like to avoid copying the auth database and read it directly from the default profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed the `profileFolder` argument in `QgsApplication`, found in the [C++ code](https://qgis.org/api/qgsapplication_8cpp_source.html#l00143) :

```
QgsApplication::QgsApplication( int &argc, char **argv, bool GUIenabled, const QString &profileFolder, const QString &platformName )
```

I adapt my code and it works :

```py
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

argvb = list(map(os.fsencode, sys.argv))
qgisapp = QgsApplication(argvb, True, "/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default", "desktop")

qgisapp.initQgis()

authM = qgisapp.authManager()
authM.setMasterPassword("myMasterPassword", True)  # returns True
print(authM.authenticationDatabasePath())
# returns '/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db'

print(authM.availableAuthMethodConfigs())
# returns {'dbconfid': <qgis._core.QgsAuthMethodConfig object at 0x____________>}
```